# jquery queue sequence updating xml

Tags: jquery, xml, queue

I am developing undo/redo feature in a xml based UI, using JQuery i load, read and update xml nodes.

```
undo_xml=actual_xml;                     //save the actual xml state before to update it,
$(this).attr("xmlattribute",newvalue);   //update a specific node with a new value
redo_xml=actual_xml;                     //save the updated xml as the redo state
```

The problem is the istruction `$(this).attr("xmlattribute",newvalue);` runs always before than `undo_xml=actual_xml`, so I never record `undo_xml` as desired.

I tryed `$.queue()`, `jquery.stackevent()` and many other way.

But,

`$(this).attr("xmlattribute",newvalue);`

always runs before xml var assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I found i solution by myself, it's not a sequence issue but a resource matter.

i hope this may help you.

```
undo_xml=$(actual_xml).clone();          //save the actual xml state before to update it,
$(this).attr("xmlattribute",newvalue);   //update a specific node with a new value
redo_xml=$(actual_xml).clone();          //save the updated xml as the redo state
```